# How to fix error on handling PanGestureRecognizer when called from another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I want to add PanGestureRecognizer to UIView of UIViewController. I'm dividing view on nine equal parts and create an UIViews by them. Also I added PanGestureRocgnizer on every part. When I call it in another class where I need it it works fine but when I touch on the screen in some part to start handle method for PangestureRecognizer I get the Error: **[UIView handlePanGestureRocognizer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17de2ee0**. This is my code:

```
#import "CustomGestureRecognizer.h"

@implementation CustomGestureRecognizer
@synthesize arrayOfPatternsForComparison;
@synthesize arrayOfSubviews;
@synthesize arrayOfPanGestureRecognizers;



- (void)initialize:(UIView *)view {
    arrayOfPatternsForComparison = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayOfSubviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayOfPanGestureRecognizers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self createPatternsForComparison];
    [self splitScreenInParts:view];
    [self setPanGestrueRecognizersOnEveryPartOfTheScreen];
}

- (void)createPatternsForComparison {

}

- (void)splitScreenInParts:(UIView *)view {
    CGSize onePart = CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width/3, view.frame.size.height/3);
    CGFloat x_positionOfPart = 0;
    CGFloat y_positionOfPart = 0;

    for (NSUInteger j=0; j<3; j++) {
        for (NSUInteger i=0; i<3; i++) {
            UIView *_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_positionOfPart, y_positionOfPart, onePart.width, onePart.height)];

            [[_view layer] setBorderWidth:1.0];
            [[_view layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];

            x_positionOfPart += onePart.width;
            [arrayOfSubviews addObject:_view];
            [view addSubview:_view];
        }
        y_positionOfPart += onePart.height;
        x_positionOfPart = 0;
    }

}

- (void)setPanGestrueRecognizersOnEveryPartOfTheScreen {
    for (UIView *view in arrayOfSubviews) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:view action:@selector(handlePanGestureRocognizer:)];
        [[panGestureRecognizer view] setTag:[arrayOfSubviews indexOfObject:view]];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}


- (void)handlePanGestureRocognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%d", [[sender view] tag]);
}



@end
```

and in another class of UIViewController I called it like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CustomGestureRecognizer *cgr = [[CustomGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [cgr initialize:[self view]];
}
```

How to fix this? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: As a side note and for future reference I wouldn't get the current index of a loop using `indexOfObject`, this approach isn't particularly efficient. Try looping with `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` this will provide both the index and the object.

Comment: `[arrayOfSubviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIView *view = obj;
        NSLog(@"////// %d", idx);
        if ([view isEqual:[sender view]]) {
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];`

I implement it like this... But get this strange log:
2015-08-20 15:18:45.716 WorxApp[711:96624] ////// 1
2015-08-20 15:18:45.717 WorxApp[711:96624] ////// 2
2015-08-20 15:18:45.718 WorxApp[711:96624] ////// 3
2015-08-20 15:18:45.718 WorxApp[711:96624] ////// 4
2015-08-20 15:18:45.718 WorxApp[711:96624] ////// 5

Comment: What's strange about it?

Comment: Thanks for your help Steve Wilford... I managed to get what I wanted. :) I find semantic error in UIPanGestureRecognizer for container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `cgr` is released when you call it.

You have to create a var `CustomGestureRecognizer *cgr` in  .h and then:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    cgr = [[CustomGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [cgr initialize:[self view]];
}
```

And then change this line

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:view action:@selector(handlePanGestureRocognizer:)];
```

to

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGestureRocognizer:)];
```

Comment: Can you try my edited answer? Change 2 places in codes

Comment: Yeah I just did that and it worked. Thanks for your help very much... ;)

Comment: Mark my answer is the answer pls. Thanks

Comment: Remember to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:view action:@selector(handlePanGestureRocognizer:)];
```

Here you are passing the target as "view" which is here a subview. The target should be a viewController object like "self" or any other viewController object.

And also here you are just creating 9 views (I think in NSObject subclass) and adding to an array, but those are not added to any view as sub views. For this you can return that array to your viewController, and there add pan gesture to those views with self as target. Then it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding var ***CustomGestureRecognizer *cgr*** in ***.h*** of another class like anhtu said and change

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:view action:@selector(handlePanGestureRocognizer:)];
```

target to ***self*** like Dev said.