# How to programmatically connect more UIPanGestureRecognizer on more views?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

How can I make one `UIPanGestureRecognizer`? I have multiple views and every one of them has their own `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. How can I make that, when user holds his finger on one and moves his finger across the screen, the tag of view is changing and also the view, until user lifts his finger from the screen? It' a little bit hard to explain... I hope you will understand. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to create a single pan gesture recogniser that will work with multiple views, and for you to know which view is currently under the users finger during the pan. If this is the case then this should help...

Create a view to act as a container for all the views you want to participate in the pan.

[image]

I've given each view it's own colour to make it visually obvious.

[image]

I've also added a label to each view to show it's tag.

Hook up a single `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the container view and attach it's selector to a method in your view controller class.

```
- (IBAction)panGestureRecognizerTriggered:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];

    // Find the view that is currently under the user's finger
    for (UIView *view in recognizer.view.subviews) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, location)) {
            NSLog(@"View %d at %@", (int)view.tag, NSStringFromCGPoint((location)));

            // Found the view, stop searching :)
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This method iterates the subviews of the view attached to the gesture recogniser and determines which subview is currently under the users finger, printing the tag and current location.

Admittedly this probably isn't going to be particularly efficient if you're dealing with lots of views but for a simple case such as this it gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and such answer... I'll try it now. And yes this is exactly what I'm trying to get. I have nine views as subviews of another view.

Comment: Cool, nine subviews shouldn't cause issues in terms of efficiency with this approach. I'd be interested to see alternatives though :)

Comment: I can't get tag of uiview but location can.

Comment: I don't follow. You get the tag of the view with view.tag as shown in my code sample.

Comment: This is my post also. Maybe you get the picture clearer about my code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114502/how-to-fix-error-on-handling-pangesturerecognizer-when-called-from-another-class

Comment: Presumably you're no longer creating pan gesture recognizers for every view with my approach. I'd guess that the view's tags are not being set. Try logging the memory address of the view instead of the tag and confirm they are different when panning.